# Getting the new filename of a file saved with ajax AsyncFileUpload?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asyncfileupload

I'm saving a file with the asyncfileupload ajax plugin from the ajax toolkit and when I save it I'm changing the filename (to avoid multiple files with the same name).

After the file is uploaded, the user needs to know what the file has been named so I'm using this javascript code on the onclientuploadcomplete event.

```
function UploadComplete(sender, args) {
    alert(args.get_fileName());
}
```

This works except it gets the old name, not the new name (which is determined server-side). Is there any way to get it to return the new name rather than the old name? Or any work around to achieve this?

This is my code in the code behind the get the new filename:

```
string filename = DateTime.Now.ToString("dMyHmsf") + e.filename;
string strPath = MapPath("~/SavedImages/") + filename;    
AsyncFileUpload1.SaveAs(strPath);
```

Answer (score 3):

I got the answer from http://forums.asp.net/post/4139037.aspx It works for me...

copied code from there:

```
<asp:ToolkitScriptManager runat="server">  
    </asp:ToolkitScriptManager>  


<!--This script snippet must be located below the ScriptManager-->  
    <script type="text/javascript">  
        Sys.Extended.UI.AsyncFileUpload.prototype.newFileName = null;  //I did not use this line
        function uploadcomplete(sender, e) {  
            alert(sender.newFileName);  
        }  
    </script>  


    <asp:AsyncFileUpload ID="AsyncFileUpload1" OnClientUploadComplete="uploadcomplete" 

        runat="server" OnUploadedComplete="AsyncFileUpload1_UploadedComplete1" />
```

the code behind:

```
protected void AsyncFileUpload1_UploadedComplete1(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AsyncFileUploadEventArgs e) 
{ 
    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, 
        this.GetType(), "newfile",  
        "window.parent.$find('" + AsyncFileUpload1.ClientID + "').newFileName='newfile.jpg';", true); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about writing the filename to a hiddenfield in the codebehind and the reading that value in your clientside code?

Comment: Good idea but won't that require a postback?